# Is the Flaming Head a pre-order bonus?

Tags: destiny

Yesterday I came across [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBGHxASf-44); a player with a 'flaming' head. Is this a pre-order bonus? Is there also a way to identify Bungie employees? (They like to stand out in the crowd).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The video seems to largely answer your question.

From the comments it comes from the weekly nightfall strike (see also [this reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/2gxrbj/whats_that_a_radiant_light_in_destiny_and_how_can/) as a reference). In the video you see them hovering over the buff "Radiant Light" which is the linked buff causing the effect. The buff apparently gives 20% bonus to XP and rep gains (see previous link and [also this gamefaq post](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/704532-destiny/70156735)).

As for bungie employees I have no idea and that would seem to be a separate question anyway.

Comment: You would be correct about the Nightfall. I have had Radiant Light the past 2 weeks now :) just beat the nightfall and you get it...until the next nightfall comes out